# WinAPI. События при переключении вкладок

Tags: winapi

На [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/create-a-tab-control-in-the-main-window) описан пример создания вкладок. Как именно происходят события при переходах между вкладками? Как это применять в функции типа

> CALLBACK  WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

чтобы  вызывать обработку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вы не совсем верно представляете себе работу вкладок. Никакого перехода между вкладками не происходит - точнее, сам контрол никаких действий не выполняет. Когда пользователь выбирает другую вкладку, контрол посылает нотификацию `TCN_SELCHANGE`, и всё, на этом его работа заканчивается. Что-то там менять - это ваша ответственность.

Работа с табами происходит следующим образом:

1) Вы создаёте контрол и добавляете туда все необходимые вкладки.

2) В клиентской области контрола создаёте своё окно, или что там вы хотите показывать. Контролу это окно совершенно безразлично, он с ним ничего не делает. Он просто родитель, причем безответственный.

3) В оконной процедуре отлавливаете `WM_NOTIFY` от контрола. Если пришла нотификация `TCN_SELCHANGE`, проверяете какая вкладка сейчас активна, и рисуете в своём окне то, что надо показывать для данной вкладки.

То есть контрол всего лишь извещает вас, что пользователь выбрал другую вкладку. А дальше сами.